# Evenly Spacing a Grid of Divs in a Container: Content Generated via Database

Tags: html, css, database, spacing

So I've looked at all of the other "Evenly spacing divs in a container" questions and answers on this website and I've found a lot of great solutions, however none of them quite answer my question.

I would like to evenly space a gallery of divs inside of a container, but all of the content is generated via database call-to's. Meaning in the database template I stylize **ONE** div according css and then the database replicates that one div into the container with different content in each. I would like the spacing to expand to bring the left and right edges of the red boxes in the JS Fiddle to the edges of the container. Here is my code thus far.

**Container Properties:**

```
.main {
display: block;
float: left;
min-height: 500px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
width: 655px;
padding: 30px;
}
```

**Div Properties:**

```
.card-container {
display: inline;
float: left;
width: 140px;
min-height: 190px;
background: #F80004;
}

.card-container + .card-container {
margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
<div class="card-container">Database Generated Content/Images</div>
<div class="card-container">Database Generated Content/Images</div>
<div class="card-container">Database Generated Content/Images</div>
<div class="card-container">Database Generated Content/Images</div>
<div class="card-container">Database Generated Content/Images</div>
<div class="card-container">Database Generated Content/Images</div>
<div class="card-container">Database Generated Content/Images</div>
<div class="card-container">Database Generated Content/Images</div>
<div class="card-container">Database Generated Content/Images</div>
</div>
```

**Js Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xxevry2s/1/

As you can see, the divs on the second line are pushed over by 5 pixels. Huge bummer. Keep in mind that I am only able to style one div inside of the Database Template, the HTML in the JS Fiddle would be generated server side. So *all of the divs have to be exactly the same*. I can't give any div container a ":last" property or break it into columns.

Any help with this would be most appreciated. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now, this will be a 2 part answer sort of:

Question and answer 1: Is the layout fluid? If answer is NO then all you need to do is this:

```
/*remove the old declaration of card-container*/
.card-container{
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
.card-container:nth-child(4n+1){
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

If the answer is YES then this becomes more problematic:

```
.main {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 655px;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align:justify;
}

.card-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    min-height: 190px;
    background: #F80004;
}
/*may need this rule as well but not always
.main::after {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    visibility: hidden;
}*/
```

I did not take into account vertical spacing. If you need vertical spacing as well, go with tables.

Comment: The first answer worked! Thanks so much :) Is there any way to make nth child work for IE before 9.0? If not, then I guess it just isn't supported.

Comment: It's a polyfill and given the choice, i would not use it, but if you must - http://selectivizr.com/